# Allowing user to input into a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

How can I create a program that allows a user to input some numbers into a text file, then from the text file randomly selects the numbers in Python 3.0

So far I've tried this:

```
input1 = input("Input: ")
input2 = input("Input: ")
file = open("text file", "w")
file.write("\n".join((input1,input2,)))
file.close()
```

That is what I have so far but I am looking for a possible way for the user to be able to input an unlimited amount of inputs.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: input1 = input("Input: ")

input2 = input("Input: ")

file = open("text file", "w")

file.write("\n".join((input1,input2,)))

file.close()

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
# Writing part:
user_input = []
while True:
    i = input('Enter your number. For end press enter:')
    if not i:
        break
    else:
        user_input.append(i)

f = open('user.txt', 'w')

for number in user_input:
    f.write(number+'\n')

f.close()

# Reading part:
numbers = []
f = open('user.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
    numbers.append(line)

f.close()

print(random.choice(numbers))
```